# Retrieving and handling an infinite amount of data

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I'm building an app for financial budget planning and I'm hitting a wall right now. In the app, the user is supposed to budget his finances each and every month.

He adds transactions – income as well as spending – and he assigns budgets to each of his categories individually, i.e. $500 for groceries. Each time he spends something on groceries, it gets subtracted from those $500. But it's also possible that he spends more on groceries than he budgeted for (= overspending) and maybe he even budgeted more money throughout his categories than he actually had (= overbudgeting).

The problem is: I somehow need to handle a theoretically infinite amount of previous data. Because everything the user overspent or overbudgeted in previous months needs to kinda bleed through till today. Which means: If the user overspent $500 in January and hasn't compensated for it yet, those $500 still need to truncate his available budget in June.

Now it were not such a big problem to calculate this month's data through last month's data, but I only get last month's correct data when calculating the month before. And this seems like and endless loop.

A simplified version of the database structure looks as follows:

**"CATEGORIES" TABLE**

id | title

**BUDGETS TABLE**

category_id | budget_date (2017-06) | amount

**TRANSACTIONS TABLE**

id | ... | date (2017-06-17) | category_id | outflow | inflow

Do you have any idea on how to proceed here? I hope I didn't overlook a similar question, but I'm not even really sure what I'm searching for. I just need to find a way to correctly calculate every month's available budget, no matter how far the overspending/overbudgeting goes in history.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

EDIT: I've added the query I've built, but it doesn't seem to work, it delivers wrong results. Any idea on how to improve it?

```
SELECT category AS category_id,  
  SUM(outflow) AS outflows,  
  SUM(inflow) AS inflows,  
  SUM(amount) AS amounts,  
  SUM(amount) - SUM(inflow) - SUM(outflow) AS total  
FROM transactions  
LEFT JOIN budgets ON (transactions.category = budgets.cat_id  
  AND DATE_FORMAT(transactions.date, "%Y-%m") = 
  DATE_FORMAT(budgets.date, "%Y-%m"))  
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(transactions.date, "%Y-%m") < "' . $date . '"  
GROUP BY transactions.category ASC
```

Comment: you need to calculate the "net sum" owed (neg or pos), and apply that to the available funds for that month.

Comment: You could do a query grouped by the categories, getting a sum of all transactions. It doesn't matter if they over/underspent in a month - because they will balance out to indicate where they are against the budget - if you join to the budget and multiply by the number of months. You could also do 2 queries: past months and current month to show current vs history.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thank you. I've tried everything, but it seemingly doesn't work the way I built the query. Would you mind taking a look at it above?

Comment: @Rogue Thanks, I'm trying, but it doesn't work so far...

Comment: What "doesn't work" in your query? Can you provide an example of the output expected and what you are currently getting?

Comment: @SloanThrasher The outflows and inflows are totally correct, the category_id grouping as well. Even the date range seems correct. However, the "amounts" are entirely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your query includes, and therefore sums, one budget row for every transaction row. Instead, it should include the budget row only once per category.

This presumes that for a given month/year date in the budgets table, there is only one row per category.

```
SELECT category AS category_id,  
    SUM(a.outflow) AS outflows,  
    SUM(a.inflow) AS inflows,  
    b.amount AS amounts,  
    b.amount - SUM(a.inflow) - SUM(a.outflow) AS total  
FROM transactions a
LEFT JOIN budgets b
    ON a.category = b.cat_id  
    AND DATE_FORMAT(MAX(a.date), "%Y-%m") = DATE_FORMAT(b.date, "%Y-%m")
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.date, "%Y-%m") < "' . $date . '"  
GROUP BY a.category ASC, b.amount
```